# Running LEDs on AC power with a series capacitor

Tags: current-limiting, series

I have been experimenting with replacing the lighting with LEDs. Recently I tried a new arrangement. I sanded the envelopes of two white LEDs such that when glued together to form a single 5 mm LED again, sort of, they are back to back. This way each LED lights on one half of the AC cycle. It is only noticeable if you wave them around.

I had to add a current limiting resistor to light them, but the resistor gets rather hot as it is punching above it weight, and a resistor of appropriate wattage is too big to fit in places where the LEDs would be placed.

When I place an electrolytic capacitor of 4.7 to 10 uF (35 V) in series with the 12 VAC power, both LEDs light as expected, but no current limiting resistors are required. In fact on the test bed, the LEDs that do have a resistor, no longer get warm to the touch. I am lighting 5 LEDs this way now all white LEDs, two of which are the back to back LEDs, and one plain jane 5 mm white LED.

This idea was inspired when I found an LED manufacturer that was putting two LEDs in a package back to back along with with an internal capacitor. These were high power LEDs for commercial lighting.

I would like to understand why this works, and if possible have an understanding of how many LEDs I can light this way on one small capacitor.

Comment: Is this "AC" at 60Hz or something much higher??   If it's thousands of Hz, you probably could light an LED through a series cap.  At 60Hz, much different situation.

Comment: You've built a simple capacitive dropper with the LEDs replacing the usual diode bridge: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply

Comment: you shouldn't use an electrolytic capacitor, eventually it could fail, even explosively. Electrolytics need to be used where there is a DC bias so the voltage across them does not reverse.

Comment: Are the LED's back-to-back or anti-parallel?

Comment: Since there is a lot of confusion, can you please post a picture in the body of the question showing your back-to-back LED's? And, if you are able, a schematic showing everything.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, putting the leds ‘back to back’ is a handy technique when using AC. If you don’t protect a led from reverse voltages (usually around 5V) it will die over time. Back to back ensures that one led is conducting and thus protects the other.

Back to your observations.  At AC, a capacitor has ‘reactance’ which is sort of equivalent to resistance but is depending on frequency. There are online calculators for this - search for ‘capacitive reactance calc’. A 4u7 capacitor at 60Hz has an effective resistance of around 564Ohms. Using Ohms law at 12VAC this means your leds get around 16mA. The leds should be happy and reliable.

One omission is the choice of capacitor - the average electrolytic capacitor is polarised- ie it only likes voltage on way. I’d suggest using a non-polar capacitor like a ceramic, non-polar electrolytic  or mylar film type.

Comment: OP is using an electrolytic capacitor on AC, maybe add something about that?

Comment: Done! Thanks Oscar.

Comment: I have seen white LED's that have very limited ability to block any kind of reverse voltage. I think they actually have silicon diodes built-in to the package in anti-parallel configuration. This type of LED actually would work in a series back-to-back configuration with AC since the silicon diode would become forward biased when the LED is reverse biased.

Answer (score 1):

During positive peak to negative peak transition of ac supply, capacitor discharges and then charges to opposite polarity with its discharging/charging current flowing through one LED. During the opposite transition of ac supply (negative peak to positive peak), capacitor's discharging/charging current flows through the other LED. So each LED is flashed on during alternate peak to peak transitions of the ac supply. Due to rapidity of ac supply frequency and a phenomenon known as "persistence of vision" the LEDs appear to be constantly lit.

Leds shouldn't be connected in parallel because they all have their own individual forward voltage drop which varies slightly from LED to LED and so if multiple LEDs were connected in parallel then current hogging can occur with the current shared unequally between the LEDs. This can damage some of the LEDS where they are forced to have more voltage across them than they "want".

The voltage across the capacitor reverses on each ac cycle and so you cannot use an ordinary polarised electrolytic capacitor. However a non-polarised electrolytic should be fine, just make sure it is suitably voltage rated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising that the 12VAC power supply can do this because AC passes through capacitors. Measure the current the capacitor by planting a meter in series. Make sure that the peak to peak value (RMS times 1.4) of the current does not exceed the max current of the LED (listed in the datasheet). If it does then limit the current with a resistor in series with the led and capacitor.

It will be difficult to find the current without measuring because the current will also depend on the phase of the load and the source ( power supply).

Comment: Sorry, A Typo, the Power is 12Volts AC, Not DC. I am so used to typing VDC I just did it automatically. The transformer is a Wall Wart style, which provides 12 VAC at about  3.3 amps. A single White LED draws ~13ma AC.

Answer (score 0):

(Clarification: Using the description back to back may not be interpreted the same by everyone. However, I'm using the term, and I'm assuming that you mean that you are placing the LEDs in parallel into your circuit, and that that they connected so that the cathode of each diode is connected to the anode of the other diode.)
By placing the LEDs back to back, you allow current in alternate directions, to alternately light each diode, during each alternate AC half cycle. During one half cycle, lets call it the positive half cycle, this positive half cycle forward biases one of the diodes, causing current to flow in it, and therefore, illuminating it. And, during the negative half cycle, the voltage is reversed, and it forward biases the other diode, causing current to flow in it, and illuminate it.
Of course, you must limit/control the current, or else the LED currents can be excessive, which will burn them up. The impedance that limits this current can be resistive, capacitive, or inductive. All you have to do is calculate the impedance needed to set the current at the value you desire, and implement it with a resistor, capacitor, or an inductor. Since your AC supply voltage is large compared to the LED voltage drop, you can ignore the diode's on resistance, since it will essentially be a short circuit compared to the current limiter impedance you will calculate.
Well, this is apparently what you have done, roughly, or you just made a great guess. By my calculations, if you have a 12 VAC RMS supply voltage, at 60 Hz, and you want to limit the current to about 20 milliAmps, you need 600 ohms. And, Xc = 1/(2piFC). And, current, I = 1/Xc. So, if you want a pretty standard current of 20 mA, then, C = I/(V x 2 x pi x F) = 0.02/(12 x 2 x 3.14 x 60) =  4.4 uF. This is close to the 4.7 uF you used. And, 10 uF will allow more current, and give you more light, which you probably got. (You can make this calculation a bit more exact, by using {12 volts - the LED voltage}, instead of 12 volts...)
Now, if you use a non-polarized capacitor, this should work fine. Of course, this assumes a steady state prevails, and one can argue that since you may have a circuit where you may get a large inrush current when you energize it, you could have an initial current that exceeds the LED's Max current. Also, you might temporarily get by with series opposing electrolytics, with bleeder resistors across each of them, but shield yourself if you try this, in preparation for possible explosions! i.e., I just wouldn't do it, ever...
Hmmm, maybe a series inductor could be considered, instead of a capacitor. This should solve the inrush liability, but inductors can create quite a high voltage if you open circuit them. i.e., instantaneously removing the AC produces a large di/dt in the inductor, which can result in a big voltage spike, which you will need to tame.
P. S., I have put very little thought into using an inductor...
Some years ago I did experiment with using a capacitor as a current limiter, and it worked well. In the experiments I was using a supply voltage of 120 VAC at 60 Hz.
Enjoy...

Comment: Paragraphs would be nice

Comment: Yes, your description of the LEDs wiring is correct, this what I meant when I said back to back. I am trying to find a lighting solution for these antique doll houses that can use LEDs instead of the incandescent lamps because they all plate out eventually and of course they burn out. Converting to DC would be one way, but the way they are wired makes this very difficult. Some cannot be disassembled to get to the wiring, so I am experimenting. Two LEDs back to back provides much more light than the single filament bulbs, so LEDs are desirable. Your answer explains a lot.

Comment: For what it is worth, I rewired about 75 christmas village ceramic houses etc. I did it with 12V and then powered them with several line powered 12V power supplies. Mine are all in one location making that solution viable.